# Cannot remove a plugin with Vundle

Tags: plugin-vundle

Other than deleting the plugin directory in `/bundle/` I have not been able to successfully uninstall a plugin. I found [this issue](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/issues/733) and have tried removing the plugin from my `vimrc`, running `:PluginInstall`, `:PluginUpdate`, and `:PluginClean`, but I cannot seem to uninstall any of the plugins with `vundle`.  This is my [Vim setup](https://github.com/robskrob/Dirty-Sprite-2). Given my linked vim setup and the commands that I have tried to run, does anyone know what could be wrong? Has anyone ran into this problem before and solved it?

Comment: I faced the same problem too. Still looking for answer.

Answer (score 10):

1. In your _vimrc delete the `Plugin 'blabla'` line you want to uninstall.
2. Execute `:PluginClean` in vim.

By the way, make sure PluginClean do the right thing
you should open a new vim window to execute `:PluginClean`

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this would help. So far it helped me.
First I went to .vim/bundle/Vundle.vim

Then I just do "git pull origin master" to pull latest code from the repo. If there is a merge conflict, settle the conflict and pull again. I dont know why, but while you are pulling from the repo, you have to quit any active editting mode on .vimrc

After that, I went back to my .vimrc, do :PluginClean and suddenly all the plugin I cannot delete is deleted properly. Then I do :PluginUpdate to update again.

Hopefully this helps.

My guess is that, vundle did not update its own code correctly.